# How to make this a if statement if the user chooses less than 3 items?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, listbox

```
    private void CheckoutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

      string[] chkItems = listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();
      textBlock1.Text = chkItems[0] + Environment.NewLine + chkItems[1] + Environment.NewLine + chkItems[2] +
          Environment.NewLine;

    }
```

I have this bit of code in my app I am creating. I have a listbox that shows some options, and they are allowed to pick up to 3 items, but my app keeps crashing if they dont pick 3 items. Is there a way to make this an if statement so they are allowed to pick either 1, 2 or even 3 items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by `foreach` loop

```
   string[] chkItems = listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();

    textBlock1.Text=string.Empty;
    foreach(string item in chkItems)
    {
      textBlock1.Text=textBlock1.Text + item +Environment.NewLine;
    }
```